# Use Letsencrypt certificates for Postgresql

Tags: debian, permissions, ssl, postgresql, letsencrypt

I have successfully configured Letsencrypt for my NGINX webserver on Debian 8 Jessie.

Now I have installed Postgresql 9.4 and want to use the LE certificates (in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/com/...`) for its SSL connection. I've set the paths to the certificate and the key in the config file ( `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`).

Predictably when I try to restart Postgres via `pg_ctlcluster` it fails because of `Permission denied` to the certificate. I understand that Postgresql is run with the user *postgres* and that this user does not have access to this directory.

How do I fix this in a clean way?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/807024/use-letsencrypt-certificates-for-postgresql